# Recycleview AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: kivy

please check why the below program is giving an

`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
# from kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect import ScrollEffect 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout


Builder.load_file('so_extractTIC.kv')


class RecycleItem(ScreenManager,RecycleDataViewBehavior, TextInput):
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(RecycleItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)


class DataView(Screen):
    DataList = ListProperty()
    TextInputNum = NumericProperty(10)
    
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(DataView, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        # for key, val in self.ids.items():
        #     print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))

        data12= []    
        for x in range(self.TextInputNum):
            data12.append({'text': '', 'height': 50})
        self.ids.rv.data = data12

    def extract_data(self,rv):
        print(self.parent.parent.parent)
        self.DataList.clear()
        for x in range(self.TextInputNum):
            self.DataList.append(self.ids.rv.data[x]['text'])
        print(self.DataList)
        




class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # self.root = Builder.load_string(APP_KV)
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
<DataView>:
    BoxLayout:        
        orientation: 'vertical'
        RecycleView:
            
            size_hint_y: 0.9
            viewclass: 'RecycleItem'
            id: rv
            key_size: 'size'
            # effect_cls: ScrollEffect
            cols: 1
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: rvbox
                cols: rv.cols
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                default_size_hint: 1, None
        Button:
            text: 'Submit'
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            on_release: root.extract_data()

<RecycleItem>:
    on_text: self.parent.parent.data[self.index]['text'] = self.text



<RootWidget>:
    DataView:
        name:"DataView_screen"
```

I have been searching for extract data from recycleview using textInput boxes. Please find the link for the query:

[Retrieve Data from Kivy Recycleview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551028/retrieve-data-from-kivy-recycleview)

I am trying to inherit from ScreenManager, but it is giving the 'super' attribute error. Tried passing id as argument in the .kv and tried to find real parent but nothing works.

Also, please suggest how to use the above code for recycle GridLaout, with 2d rows and columns, i tried using for loops, but getting key related errors.
like:

```
for z in range(12):
            for y in range(8): 
                self.table_data12.append(self.ids.idname.data[y][z]['text'])
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DataView` class, the `__init__()` method references `self.ids`, but the `ids` are not yet available at that point. You can delay that referencing by using `Clock.schedule_once()` like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DataView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # for key, val in self.ids.items():
    #     print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))

    Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_data)

def setup_data(self, dt):
    data12 = []
    for x in range(self.TextInputNum):
        data12.append({'text': '', 'height': 50})
    self.ids.rv.data = data12
```

I see no reason for making the `RecycleItem` a subclass of `ScreenManager`.

In your 'kv`, the` on_text`line for`RecycleItem` can be:

```
<RecycleItem>:
    on_text: app.root.get_screen('DataView_screen').ids.rv.data[self.index]['text'] = self.text
```

And the submit `Button` can be:

```
    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        on_release: root.extract_data(rv)
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Removed RecycleItem as subclass of ScreenManager.